# AlarmManager BroadcastReceiver, onReceive never called

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin.android, alarmmanager

I am making an alarm clock app and I wanted to test AlarmManager Class to schedule an event for me to perform when the app is closed not a regular OS alarm my own custom alarm thats why I'm not using AlarmClock class. for some reason OnReceive() method in my class that extends BroadcastReceiver is never getting called? I hope you guys can help. Also if there is a better tecnique to implement a scheduled interupt i would be glad to know, id like youre input. also note i have tried putting the receiver tag like this

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReciever"></receiver>
```

in between the application tags in my manifest but i get same results, also i Know that i mispelled Reciever in my Class definition but i kept in consistent throughout project.

here is my maifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Alarm_clock_app.Alarm_clock_app" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
  <application android:label="Alarm_clock_app">
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
</manifest>
```

this is the method i call in my main activity inside onCreate(), this method is inside my main activity class

```
 public void sched()
        {


            Intent intent = new Intent(this,typeof(MyReciever));//create an intent with our custom broadcast reciever

            PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(this,0,intent,PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);//get a pending intent made from our intent

            AlarmManager alarM = (AlarmManager) GetSystemService(AlarmService);//get alarm manager

            alarM.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, DateTime.Now.Millisecond + 5 * 1000, pIntent);//schedule the alarm for 5,000 ms from now

        }
```

this is my class that extends broadcast reciever

```
   [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Process = ":remote")]
    class MyReciever: BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("alarm has occuered"); 

        }
    }
```

Comment: You're using the `PendingIntent.GetService()` method, which is used to start a `Service`. If you want to broadcast to a `BroadcastReceiver`, use the `PendingIntent.GetBroadcast()` method instead. (Btw, if you edit your question, it gets bumped to the top of the active queue. You don't need to post another question for the same thing, especially not one that just links to a previous question.)

Comment: thanks but this did not fix the issue

Comment: OK, when you edit your question, make sure it's worthwhile. Don't just change a single letter to get it bumped. Update your code to what you're currently running, add any new behavior you're observing, link to any other posts or examples that you've tried to implement, etc. At least fix your grammar, punctuation, and spelling if you edit it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change first argument of alarm. set method 
and/or to use Calendar date setting:

```
{Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
 alarM.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);}
```